# How to disable screen lock during Android development?

Tags: applications, adb, security, lock-screens

I am developing Android app with my daily phone, I want to turn off screen lock only during development.

I can do this manually, but that is too troublesome and sometimes I forget to enable it back after development.

Are there ways to do this automatically? i.e. turn off screen lock when connected to USB?

Answer (score 14):

There are other ways too. My favorite is:

```
$ adb shell svc power stayon true
```

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840954/how-do-i-keep-my-screen-unlocked-during-usb-debugging

Comment: This command will keep the device on not only for USB but also for Wireless or AC adapter charging.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Go to `Settings` -> `Developer options` and turn on the `Stay awake` option.

Answer (score 0):

So I faced this problem too and I got quite annoyed at having to go into settings and enable "stay awake" and then disable it when I'm done. Searching the Play Store for an app to do it autonomously, and tried a few that claimed to work but didn't, so I made my own...

And the code is available open-source here: https://github.com/projectdelta6/ADB-Stay-Awake#adb-stay-awake

Answer (score 0):

I created simple shell script for my **macOS**

File Name : cell-screen.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

echo '`cell-screen on` to keep the screen on during usb debugging'
echo '`cell-screen off` to reset'

echo ''
echo 'your parameter - ' $1

if [[ "$1" = "on" ]]; then
    ~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb shell settings put global stay_on_while_plugged_in 2
elif [[ "$1" = "off" ]]; then
    ~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb shell settings put global stay_on_while_plugged_in 0
else
    echo '\n[****]Bad Input.'
fi

echo '\nEnd'
```

Steps:

1. I saved the script to the default use location - `/Users/[your username]`
2. Given executable access to the file - `chmod +x ~/cell-screen.sh`
3. Whenever I start my development tasks, I just execute the shell script in terminal - `~/cell-screen.sh on`
4. After I complete my development work, I simply execute - `~/cell-screen.sh off`

**For Windows Users:**

Change the shell script for the adb location - `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb`